# Bind Angular routerLink to DOM Element

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular2-routing

I have the below string which I have bound to a DOM element's 'innerHTML'.  I have sanitized it so the browser does not remove it.  The routerLink is not working.  If I change it to href then it does work.  How can I get Angular to bind this link?

**HTML string being bound**

```
<a routerLink='/somelink'>Something</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`routerLink='/somelink'` is a way of telling Angular how to behvae when you click on the link.

It isn't a native Javascript behavior.

If you use `innerHTML` to add this to your component, this will **never** work. Using `routerLink='/somelink'` works only **when your code isn't compiled**.

To visualize this, let's take `(click)` as an example, since it is the same case. Look at the snippet below :

```html
<button (click)="alert('working')">(click)</button>
<button onclick="alert('working')">onclick</button>
```

Click on both buttons and see which one works. This is because **Angular compiles your code according to its syntax**. And `routerLink` is part of its syntax, not part of native Javascript.

Comment: I don't follow according to https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#how-to-use the second line says you can write a routerLink the way it is shown above what am I missing?  I have also written routerLinks as above and they work fine but do I need to change them?

Comment: `routerLink` in compiled code works as much as `(click)`. Is `(click)` a native way of handling click elements to you ? Do you think you can write this on an attribute in a javascript file ?

Comment: OH HA! I completely missed that, sorry. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code to dynamically compile the routerLink at run-time.  I have tried it and it works.

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mcvILwmOLvrS2PxIrXX8?p=preview)

```
function createComponentFactory(compiler: Compiler, metadata: Component): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);

@NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp] })
class DynamicHtmlModule { }

return compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule)
   .then((moduleWithComponentFactory: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
    return moduleWithComponentFactory.componentFactories.find(x => x.componentType === decoratedCmp);
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink), as well as an example:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/yourpath']">Your Route</a>
```

Comment: I think he knows that, it isn't his issue.